# How plot heart curve in scilab?

Tags: plot, scilab, maple

I have been looking in the forum and within the graphical functions of the program help, how to graph the following function:

```
x2=[-2:0.02:2]';x1=[-1:0.01:1]';
function val = Heart(x1, x2) 
    val=(1.2*x2-sqrt(abs(x1)))^2+x1^2-1;
endfunction
```

And I have not found anything to guide me. 
I try to reproduce this maple plot:
Heart curve

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your defining a 3D surface, you can use `contour` and `contour2d`: as said by [luispauloml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46422543/how-plot-heart-curve-in-scilab/46425564#comment79868861_46425564), you can pass the function directly as a parameter.

```
x1=[-1:0.01:1]
x2=[-2:0.02:2]
function val = Heart(x1, x2) 
    val=(1.2*x2-sqrt(abs(x1))).^2+x1.^2-1; // switched ^ to .^ to handle vectors
endfunction;

figure()
xlabel('x1')
ylabel('x2')

contour2d(x1,x2,Heart,[0 0]); 

a=gca()
hline=a.children.children(1)
hline.foreground=color('red')
hline.thickness=2
```

[image: 1]]

Comment: Do you actually need ``xx1`` and ``xx2``? Doing just ``x1=-1:0.01:1; x2=-2:0.02:2; contour2d(x1,x2,Heart,[0 0]);`` seems to work fine.

Comment: It does ! I don't understand why since the help never specified we could pass a function as an argument but this code is far better ! You should propose an answer.

Comment: It does allow it to be a function, you probably simply missed that info on the [help page](https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.0.0/en_US/contour2d.html): "z: [...] a Scilab function which defines the surface z=f(x,y)." Also, there's no need for a new answer since it's the same solution. Just an update, which you already did, is enough. Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 1):

an other solution is to solve the equation (1.2*x2-sqrt(abs(x1)))^2+x1^2-1 = c
for x2
The  solution is quite easy
and one can found 2 branches
    x2=(5/6)*(sqrt(abs(x1))+sqrt(c+1-x1^2));
and 
    x2=(5/6)*(sqrt(abs(x1))-sqrt(c+1-x1^2));

```
c=0;
x1=linspace(-1,1,200);
x1r=x1($:-1:1);
x2=(5/6)*[ (sqrt(abs(x1))+sqrt(c+1-x1^2)) (sqrt(abs(x1r))-sqrt(c+1-    x1r^2))];
clf;plot([x1 x1r],x2);
```