# Heart function diff equals zero

Tags: diff, zero, scilab

I would like to find the values of the function for which its derivative is equal to zero.

```
function val = Heart(x1, x2) 
    val=(1.25*x2-sqrt(abs(x1))).^2+x1.^2-1;
endfunction;
```

I've tried it with the `numderivative` function.

Answer (score 1):

Scilab cannot solve this problem in the way your function is currently defined because `Heart()` is an implicit function. As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34560820/implicit-differentiation-with-scilab), Scilab is not capable of doing implicit differentiation. Moreover, your equation actually defines a 3D surface, so what you can calculate are actually partial derivatives.

If you want to find the `x1` values in which the derivative in relation to `x1` of the implicit curve `0=Heart(x1,x2)` are zero, you can use the method presented in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46422543/how-plot-heart-curve-in-scilab/46450499#46450499) from your own previous question to solve this.

If you inspect the plot of heart curve, you'll see that there are only two points where the derivative is zero (two maxima): they are located in the upper part of the curve and are near `x1=-0.6` and `x1=0.6`, respectively. To find more approximate values of these points, you should do the following:

1. Take the upper part of the heart (use [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?query=0%3D(1.25*y-sqrt(abs(x)))%5E2%2Bx%5E2-1&equal=Submit&i=0%3D(1.25*x2-sqrt(abs(x1)))%5E2%2Bx1%5E2-1) to find it) and define a new function.
2. Use `numderivative()` to define its derivative, `d_heart()`. The answer we are looking for are the zeros of this function.
3. Use `fsolve()` to solve `0=d_heart(x1)`. You should input two guesses and they can be -0.6 and 0.6.

Something like this:

```
function y = heart_up(x1)
    y = 4/5 * (sqrt(abs(x1))+sqrt(1-x1.^2))
endfunction

function y = d_heart(x1)
    y = numderivative(heart_up, x1);
endfunction

x1 = fsolve(-0.6, d_heart); y1 = heart_up(x1);
x2 = fsolve( 0.6, d_heart); y2 = heart_up(x2);
```

You can visualize that `heart_up()` is really the upper part of the heart and that the results are right by plotting them:

```
x = -1:0.01:1;
contour2d(x, 2*x, Heart, [0 0]);
plot2d(x, heart_up(x), 2);
plot2d([x1 x2], [y1 y2], -2);
```

[image: 4]

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to shorten (improve) this script? I think of the Jacobian Heart function, evaluate it and find the points where it is zero. Some rides !!!

Following the indications of **luispauloml**:

```
[function val = Heart(x1, x2) 
    val=(1.25*x2-sqrt(abs(x1))).^2+x1.^2-1;
endfunction;


function y = heart_up(x1)
    y = 4/5 * (sqrt(abs(x1))+sqrt(1-x1.^2))
endfunction
function y = heart_down(x1)
    y = 4/5 * (sqrt(abs(x1))-sqrt(1-x1.^2))
endfunction

function y = du_heart(x1)
    y = numderivative(heart_up, x1);
endfunction
function y = dd_heart(x1)
    y = numderivative(heart_down, x1);
endfunction

x1 = fsolve(-0.6, du_heart); y1 = heart_up(x1);disp(y1,"y1",x1,"x1");
x2 = fsolve( 0.6, du_heart); y2 = heart_up(x2);disp(y2,"y2",x2,"x2");
x3 = fsolve( 0.0, du_heart); y3 = heart_up(x3);disp(y3,"y3",x3,"x3");
x4 = fsolve( 0.0, dd_heart); y4 = heart_down(x4);disp(y4,"y4",x4,"x4");

x = -1:0.01:1;
contour2d(x, 2*x, Heart, \[0 0\]);
plot(\[x1 x2\],\[y1 y2\],'gd');
plot(\[x3 x4\],\[y3 y4\],'rx');
replot(\[-1.415,-1,1.415,1.415\]);][1]
```

Another possible solution is:
With this function we have begun to familiarize ourselves with Scilab.
In the script that I propose we have found the critical or extreme points of the Heart function.
We call your attention in reading the comments !!!!

```
function val = Hxyg(x,y)
    val=(1.25*y-sqrt(abs(x))).^2+x.^2-1;
endfunction;
x = -1:0.01:1;
contour2d(x, 2*x, Hxyg, [0 0]);
replot([-1.415,-1,1.415,1.415]);

//We define the Hxy function with x as additional input argument( as a parameter)
//Since y, will be our unknown, we have interposed x and y in the argument list of the Hxy function 
//(y it is the unknown and x is the parameter). 
//This will be necessary to determine the intersects on the Y axis
function val = Hxy(y,x)
    val=(1.25*y-sqrt(abs(x))).^2+x.^2-1; // switched .^ to ^ to handle vectors
endfunction;
function [val] = HH(v)//v:(y,x)
    x=v(2);
    y=v(1); 
    val=Hxy(y,x);
endfunction;

function Jpx=dfx(v)//v:(y,x)
Jpx=numderivative(HH,v);
Jpx=Jpx(2);
endfunction

//Find the local maxima.
function Z = flm(v)//v:(y,x)
   Z = [ HH(v)
         dfx(v)
       ]
endfunction
//v:(y,x)
xlm1=fsolve([1.4;-0.4],flm)
disp(xlm1)
xlm2=fsolve([1.4;0.4],flm)
disp(xlm2)
plot([xlm1(2) xlm2(2)],[xlm1(1) xlm2(1)],'gx')

//Find the y-intercepts. Hxy(y,x) 
//the Hxy function uses x as a parameters.
//We define the Hxy function with x as additional input argument( as a parameter),
//which is declared after the y unknown. Then we pass a list as the second input argument
//of the  fsolve function after initial value of  Hxy function argument; in this situation only  variable y.
//The first element of the list is the Hxy function. The additional variable x is directly passed to the Hxy function.
x=0.0; 
yint1=fsolve(1,list(Hxy,x))// --->Hxy(y,x)=>1.5625*y^2-1 
disp(yint1) 
yint2=fsolve(-1,list(Hxy,x))// ---> Hxy(y,x)=>1.5625*y^2-1 
disp(yint2) 
plot([x x],[yint1 yint2],'rx')
```

[Heart Critical points or extreme points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCDCu.jpg)